# How to use objects for storing global variables? Best practice

Tags: javascript

I'm new to OOP in JavaScript, since I always worked with some frameworks and my own simple constructs, but never thought about what happened under the hood. Now, I want to tackle one problem which many JS programmers face - global variables. I know it's a bad practice to make global variables and many suggest using objects instead. And this is where a problem pops up. I do not know what is the best way to create an object and to call it somewhere in the application to get global variable values. For example, I'm not sure whether to use init function or not and how to return a global variable value (through a function or by "dot" notation). I've seen a bunch of examples concerning objects but they looked different in style. Imagine a concrete example. I want to store global variables in an object - window's height and window's width. To make it cross-browser I will use this code

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    w = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth, // this is global variable
    h = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight; // and this is global varibale too
```

So, how to apply this code inside an abject and how to get these global variables' values somewhere in the application?

**EDIT**

Now, my code looks like this:

```
var module = (function(){
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
height = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
return {
  getHeight:function(){
     return height;
  },
  getWidth:function(){
     return width;
  }
}
}());
```

To access `height` and `width` attributes I call `getHeight` and `getWidth` methods. The only thing which looks strange to me is these `returns` inside the overlapping `return`. Is it a right way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you to **avoid Globals**.

Global variables are a terribly bad idea.

**Reason:** You run the danger of your code being overwritten by any other JavaScript added to the page after yours.

**Workaround:** Use closures and the module pattern

**Sample Code to explain modules and closures**:

```
module = function(){
   var current = null;
   var labels = {
      'home':'home',
      'articles':'articles',
      'contact':'contact'
   };
   var init = function(){
   };
   var show = function(){
      current = 1;
   };
   var hide = function(){
      show();
   }
   return{init:init, show:show, current:current}
}();
module.init();
```

**YOUR CODE:**

```
var module = (function(){
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
height = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
    var getWidth = function(){
        console.log(width);
        return width;
}
    var getHeight = function(){
        console.log(height);
        return height;
}
    return{getWidth:getWidth, getHeight:getHeight}
}());
module.getHeight();
module.getWidth();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WnLgc/)**</kbd>

Comment: One tiny extra question concerning your example. To get, say, the value of the `current` variable somewhere in the application, I should write `module.current`? Or, it's better to invoke a function. The catcth is, I'm just not sure whether `return` block should actually return all atributes. If the object contains a dozen of attributes, but I want get a value of one particular attribute - should I actually return everything or can I access just one needed atribute? Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Jacobian.. I agree with you.. it's better to invoke a function and return the variables instead of writing `module.current`. Above example just explains how to use module patterns and closures. You can use based on your own requirement. For your question, If you need only one attribute better to retrieve one, if you are going to use other attributes further retrieve object and then use it.

Comment: Could you, please, have a look at my extra code above? Probably, I still do not get something or do it in a bad-style way.

Comment: @Jacobian Updated my code. Dont put everything in one return which will cause you a problem to parse. Better to use the way which I mentioned in code.

Comment: Wow! Now it looks absolutely stylish! Thank you, sir!